# How to use UNION ALL without null values for column count mismatch

Tags: postgresql

I have below tables

```
select id,name from t1

id  name
1   A
2   B
```

---

```
select id,name,sal from t2

id name sal
1   C   1000
2   D   2000
```

---

```
select id,name,Null as sal from t1 
UNION ALL
select id,name,sal from t2

id  name sal
1   A   null
2   B   null
1   C   1000
2   D   2000
```

---

But I need like this without null can we use union all option

```
id  name sal
1   A
2   B
1   C   1000
2   D   2000
```

---

Comment: What do you want to get instead of `NULL` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can try to add an empty string for `T1`, let sal's type as a string.

```
SELECT id,name,'' sal
FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT id,name,sal::TEXT
FROM T2
```